# WPF app debuging - visual studio exits debug, running .exe is fine

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017

I start debugging WPF app, 
I get several The thread 0xab5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
finally The program '[24388] MyApp.dgdg.exe ' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

When I run MyApp.dgdg.exe from bin/Debug it runs fine.

Please help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The thread has exited with code 0 (0x0) with no unhanded exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410548/the-thread-has-exited-with-code-0-0x0-with-no-unhanded-exception)

Comment: it could be a simple Thread Exit Message. Can you provide some information, My magic cristal ball provider charge me extra when we have to guess with so little information

Answer (score 0):

This is just a harmless Visual Studio debugging message that you can safely ignore or switch off by simply right-clicking in the output window and uncheck the "Thread Exit Messages" option.

It's not an error.

Comment: Ok, but the real problem is that I can not debug app.
It exits debug mode and well, no debugging for me. Just running .exe is not good enough, I need to debug app.

Comment: Are you closing the main window or something? As long as you open a window and keep it open, your app should continue to run.