# Visual studio 2017 and 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

After running any program in Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2019, I get this message:

"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\C++Files\Practice\Debug\Practice.exe (process 17832) exited with code 0"

Is there a way to get rid of this message?? It's just annoying and makes it hard to see what my program is doing. I've tried messing with several settings and can't find it yet. I get the same message in both visual studios 2017 and 2019.

Comment: You've provided least information about the error. The answers may be inaccurate even if given one.

Comment: Debug > Options > General > Automatically close the console when debugging stops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The thread has exited with code 0 (0x0) with no unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410548/the-thread-has-exited-with-code-0-0x0-with-no-unhandled-exception)

Answer (score 0):

try to go to "Debug" -> "options" -> "General" -> then check the "automatically close the console when debugging stops" button. I'm pretty sure Visual Studio automatically has that on, so unchecking it may help